# plot.subplot ---> 'Figure' object has no attribute 'plot'

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to use subplots similar to what is being shown here:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html

```
axarr = plt.subplots(len(column_list), sharex=True)
subp_num = 0
for j in column_list:
     axarr[subp_num].plot(df.values[2:,j])
     subp_num = subp_num + 1
```

then I get this error:

```
axarr[subp_num].plot(df.values[2:,j])
AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

Any hint on what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have one obvious problem: all of the examples in the link you provide look like

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(...)
```

where the `f` is the `Figure` you are subsequently treating as if it had a `plot` attribute. If you are working with an arbitrary number of subplots, you could do:

```
axarr = plt.subplots(...)
f, axarr = axarr[0], axarr[1:]
```

Also, you are using a `while` loop with an incrementing index, which is clumsy and prone to error; just use a `for` loop:

```
for j, ax in zip(column_list, axarr):
    ax.plot(df.values[2:, j])
```